# Mark and Search for marked location on map

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I want to mark all the location available in the database on the Map.After that I want to create an API which will accept the location of the user and it will return all the marked location within a range of 500 metres.Please provide me with appropriate solution

Comment: Please read [ask] and make an [edit] with what you've tried.

Answer (score -1):

As a first step, you can store the locations in mongodb as [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/). Then you can use mongodb's geospatial queries ([tutorial and related links](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/)) to return locations within the specified range. Using the returned data, you can plot markers on a map using [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/). Leaflet.js has support for GeoJSON, so you can use the returned data without much modifications.